# Lookup Filter Based on Selected Picklist Value Using Apex and Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

Let's say I have an object named **Device__c**. This has a picklist field named **Type__c**, which has two values: **Laptop** and **Mobile**.

Upon selecting **Laptop**, a picklist named **Brand__c** must be displayed. **Brand__c** picklist field contains two values: **Apple** and **Acer**.

Upon selecting **Apple**, a lookup field named **Models__c** must be displayed.

My question is, how can I filter this lookup field with such controlling picklist fields using Apex and visualforce?

By the way, here's my code:

**vf page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Device__c">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >


            <apex:selectList label="Device Type:" value="{!Device__c.Type__c}" size="1">  

                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="b1" status="status"/>              
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="--None--" itemLabel="--None--"/> 
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="Laptop" itemLabel="Laptop"/> 
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="Mobile" itemLabel="Mobile"/> 
            </apex:selectList> 
            <apex:actionStatus startText="applying value..." id="status"/> <br/>



            <apex:pageBlockSection id="b1"> 
                <apex:selectList label="Brand" value="{!Device__c.Brand__c}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Apple" itemLabel="Apple"/> 
                 <apex:selectOption itemValue="Acer" itemLabel="Acer"/>             
                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Device__c.Models__c}" rendered="{!Device__c.Type__c='Laptop'}"/> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Device__c.Device_Brand__c}" rendered="{!Device__c.Type__c='Laptop'}"/> 

            </apex:pageBlockSection> 

        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Comment: As `Type__c` and `Brand__c` are picklists, you can directly put the options in object definition. You don't need to put those in VF page. And what is the field `Device_Brand__c` stands for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify lookup filter criteria.

Let's assume you have object Device and Model

Model has text field brand and name

Device has picklist brand and lookup to model

Click on your lookup field, click edit and proceed to Lookup filter section

```
                    field           operator    value
Filter Criteria     model:  Brand   equals      Device: Brand
Filter Type Required. The user-entered value must match filter criteria.
```

Now when you selecting brand picklist, lookup will be filtered:

[image]